# Rails 4: one ActionMailer, different layouts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer

Is there a way to tell a mailer (e.g: `class Notifier < ActionMailer::Base`) to use different layouts for different methods (mails)?

I'd want to send two kinds of mails, `mail_type_1` and `mail_type_2`. Each type has its own layout, but there are multiple mails that use each of these layouts, and each of these mails has its own view.

I'd like to manage this as I do with controllers, where I can tell Rails to use different layouts for different actions, but keeping separated views for each action. This way I'd have:

```
app/views/layouts/notifier
| -> mail_layout_1.html.erb
| -> mail_layout_2.html.erb
```

which would have `yield' calls inside, and

```
app/views/notifier
| -> mail1.html.erb
| -> mail2.html.erb
| -> mail3.html.erb
| -> mail4.html.erb
```

which would fill those `yield` placeholders with `content_for`s calls. So, for example, `mail1.html.erb` and `mail2.html.erb` would be rendered using `mail_layout_1.html.erb` and `mail3.html.erb` and `mail4.html.erb` would be rendered using `mail_layout_2.html.erb`.

Is there an easy way to achieve that? The only solution I found so far is having different mailer classes